# finding the least common multiple

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, numbers

```
a = int(input(''))
b = int(input(''))
g = 0


def fac(n):
    if n <= a:
        return a
    else:
        return n * fac(n - 1)


numbers = []
i = a
while a <= i <= b:
    if a <= i <= b:
        numbers.append(i)
        i += 1
    else:
        break

for k in range(b, fac(b)):
    for l in numbers:
        if k % l == 0:
            g = k

print(g)
```

I am making a code that calculates the least common multiple of the numbers in range. I have checked the fac function and the while(if,else) I think there is a problem in the for part. I cant find the wrong part.

Comment: Can you add the output?

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your logic to find the least common multiple but you can do like this:

```
a = int(input(''))
b = int(input(''))
g = 0


if a > b:  
    g = a  
else:  
    g = b  
while(True):  
    if((g % a == 0) and (g % b == 0)):   
        break  
    g += 1 

print(g)
```

Comment: i have to find the least common multiple number with multiple numbers for example if a is 9 and b is 13 i have to find a common multiple number of 9,10,11,12,13 so i made the fac function to decide the range(Multiply all the values in the range would be the maximum) and add the numbers between a,b to the list numbers

Answer (score 0):

> I am making a code that calculates the least common multiple of the numbers in range. I have checked the fac function and the while(if,else) I think there is a problem in the for part. I cant find the wrong part.

I'm afraid I have to say that the wrong part is the whole program, because I don't think the [*fac*torial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) function is of use for the problem, and *the for part* doesn't make any sense, at least to me. Here's my suggestion for finding the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of all numbers in a range. To save some time, it first determines the set of possible prime factors and then uses this for the prime factorization of the numbers, which is finally used to compute the lcm.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
# collect possible prime factors of numbers up to b
h = 2        # highest prime so far
primes = [h] # list to store primes
n = 3        # next number to check
while n*h <= b:
    for p in primes:
        if p*p > n:
            h = n            # new prime
            primes.append(h) # enlist it
            break
        if not n%p: break
    n += 2
# prime factorization of all numbers in range a to b
factors = []
for n in range(a, b+1): # range() wants end+1
    factor = {}
    for p in primes:
        while not n%p:  # divisible: count p as factor
            factor[p] = factor.get(p, 0) + 1
            n //= p
        if (n == 1): break
    else: factor[n] = 1
    factors.append(factor)
# reduce the b-a+1 factorizations to one common
factor = {}
for f in factors:
    factor = {k: max(factor.get(k, 0), f.get(k, 0)) for k in factor|f.keys()}
# produce the lcm from the common factors
lcm = 1
for p, e in factor.items(): lcm *= p**e
print(lcm)
```